# There is an invisible force-field around my player that pushes the enemy back

Tags: unity-game-engine

My enemy just can't move past a point and it tries to push the player. If my player moves the enemy just flies off the grid.

There is only a Rigidbody component added to my enemy and a character controller component added to my player. There is not a single other Rigidbody or collider component.

This is the code that does my enemy movement:

```
if (direction.magnitude > 0.35 && zombie.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0)[0].clip.name != "Zombie Attack")
{
    pos = this.transform.position;
    pos.z = pos.z + speed;
    this.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(pos);
    zombie.SetBool("isWalking", true);
    zombie.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
}
```

I think there is something in the Player GameObject that pushes my enemy but I removed every collider and Rigidbody.

Comment: @derHugo please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that: `Transform.Translate` is moving the transform component while ignoring physics.

If you move them via. `Rigidbody.MovePosition` they should be able to collide.

Comment: I am using Raycast for shooting and adding Rigidbody is creating an issue is there an alternative way.

Comment: @JayanPaliwal Would be nice if you could add some code to see what is not working and if you really want an alternative you can either add a DistanceCheck (Pistolshot is an object and you check the distance to the target) or add a PhysicsCollider(Pistolshot is an object with a collider and you check if it collided with a target)

Comment: There is a thing like an invisible force field around my player which pushes the zombie back. I tried debugging it through onCollisionEnter and OnTriggerEnter but there is nothing that should push the zombie. I even tried disabling all the colliders on my player but still it is responding the same way. Do you have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: I would change the Enemys Collider IsTrigger Checkbox to true or false and look what happens than. If you do that OnTriggerEnter should be called on the Enemy and you can check for the Tag of the Player to see if they both collided.

Comment: I tried everything removing colliders, adding colliders, checking, and unchecking isTrigger. I attached the piece of code to the question if you could check it, I would be grateful. I could not incorporate the whole code but a part that includes the Rigidbody.movePosition